# What is probability that: (a)a non leap year has 53 Sundays. (b)a leap year has 53 fridays.

Tags: probability, experimental-mathematics

This one really bowled me over. I don't understand from where I should begin.
*I actually thought that a non leap year will have 52 weeks and 1 day. But I couldn't think how to find the probability .*
I think we are more concerned with having 53 Sundays in (a) part. In a non leap year there are 52 weeks and 1 day extra, this means  that there are 52 Sunday already and the given condition wants that the 1 day which was extra should also be Sunday ( then there would be 53 Sundays in total). There is only one possible way for this. So favourable outcome becomes one. But I am not clear about total outcomes.
Please someone help

Comment: For $(a)$, you have to find the probability that the one extra day is a Sunday and for $(b)$ that one of those two days is a Friday.

Comment: I would personally write a script to check this rather than do this with pen/paper. 
 The Gregorian calendar repeats once every $400$ years.  You can look at the $400$ years and break them apart as leap years or non-leap years.  Precisely $94$ of the years in the repeating cycle are leap years and the rest are non-leap years.  Check how many of the nonleap years have $53$ sundays and divide the result by $306$, and check how many of the leap years have $53$ fridays and divide the result by $94$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that a non-leap year has 53 of a specific day of the week if and only if Jan1 of that year is that day of the week.  Meanwhile a leap year has $53$ of a specific day of the week if and only if Jan1 or Jan2 is that day of the week.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you are asking.  If, say, you assume that Jan $1$ is equally likely to occur on any day of the week, then the problem is straight forward.  Alas, that assumption is not accurate.  See, e.g., [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/210/end-of-the-world-on-a-sunday)

Comment: The question is this much only. I think we are more concerned with having 53 Sundays in (a) part